# How do I start a new line for each group of inline blocks?

Tags: html, css

So I have multiple div tags, each one represents a inline-block. Each div has an image and headings as text. I want to be able to display them side by side, as seen from this image:

[image: https://imgur.com/Vc3kTim]

(For this image, see the "Getting Started" section, as this is what I'm referring to specifically.)

My question is how do I achieve this structure? I've tried positioning the images and text side to side, but it didn't work in the code below.

```css
.Getting-Started {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.Step1,
.Step2,
.Step3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

br {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.Step1 {}

.Step2 {}

.Step3 {}
```

```html
<div class="Getting-Started">
  <h1 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">Getting Started</h1>

  <div class="Step1">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <h2 style="margin: 0px;">Step 1: Select your year level above</h2>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="Step2">
    <img src="#" alt="#" width="">
    <h2>Step 2: Choose a level of difficulty you feel cofident with</h2>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="Step3">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <h2>Step 3: Select a topic and click on "Read More"</h2>
  </div>
  <br>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ct69hkbg/

Comment: You are setting the containers "Step" as inline-block but this does not make the elements inside it inline-block. <img> is inline but <h2> is block so takes up the whole width of its "step" container so they can't be next to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in your css making div elements with class "step1, step2, step3" to `inline-block`.
You have to make `display` of children of these elements to `inline-block`

```
.Getting-Started {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.step h2,
.step img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.step img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

br {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

refactored your code a bit and replaced "step1, step2, step3" to step as you can see in the code

check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/gj02r3dn/

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your Step1...3 classes from your HTML and your CSS.
2. Remove the `<br>` tags.
3. Use `div:nth-of-type(odd) img` and `div:nth-of-type(odd) img` selectors to
   float your images left/right alternatingly.

```css
.Getting-Started {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

br {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.Getting-Started div:nth-of-type(odd) img {
  float: left;
}

.Getting-Started div:nth-of-type(even) img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="Getting-Started">
  <h1 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">Getting Started</h1>

  <div>
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <h2>Step 1: Select your year level above</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="#" alt="#" width="">
    <h2>Step 2: Choose a level of difficulty you feel confident with</h2>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <h2>Step 3: Select a topic and click on "Read More"</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Simple Code

**HTML**

```
<h3>
    <span class="first-label">This is the main label</span>
    <span class="secondary-label">secondary label</span>
</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
 .first-label:after {
    content: '\A';
    white-space: pre; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```css
.Getting-Started {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.Step {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row-reverse; 
   justify-content: space-between;
   align-items: center;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   text-align: right;
}

.Step:nth-child(2n) {
   flex-direction: row; 
   text-align: left;
}

.Step h2 {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="Getting-Started">
  <h1 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">Getting Started</h1>

  <div class="Step">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <h2 style="margin: 0px;">Step 1: Select your year level above</h2>
  </div>


  <div class="Step">
    <img src="#" alt="#" width="">
    <h2>Step 2: Choose a level of difficulty you feel cofident with</h2>
  </div>


  <div class="Step">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <h2>Step 3: Select a topic and click on "Read More"</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

heading element `<h1>` through `<h6>`, hence can't be displayed inline or inline-block. Use inline elements instead for eg. span.
https://jsfiddle.net/snehansh/xdw9cp50/4/

```css
.Getting-Started {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.Step1, .Step2, .Step3 {
  display: inline-block;
}

br {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

.Step1 {

}

.Step2 {

}

.Step3 {

}
```

```html
<div class="Getting-Started">
  <h1 style="margin: 0 0 20px;">Getting Started</h1>

  <div class="Step1">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <span>Step 1: Select your year level above</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <div class="Step2">
    <img src="#" alt="#" width="">
    <span>Step 2: Choose a level of difficulty you feel cofident with</span>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="Step3">
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <span>Step 3: Select a topic and click on "Read More"</span>
  </div>
  <br>

</div>
```